# Have to run app twice for it to recognize change

Tags: android, io, java.util.scanner

I have an app that can take a text file from the devices internal storage and reads the contents of the file to which it places it into an arraylist for me to compare against some other data.

Some example data in the text file is:

```
1.10
1.11
1.12
```

My app displays the last element of the array list, so in this example it would be '1.12' that is displayed.

The issue I am having is that if I change '1.12' to '1.13', it only updates to the new value when I run the app for the second time.

I can't figure out why this is.  I have tested to make sure the file does update using adb and thats all updated but it appears as if the app is still reading the contents of the old version of the file rather than the new overwritten file on the first run. My code is below for reading the files contents.

```
    public void readVersionList(){
    download = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.download_version_path);
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/sdcard/version-nums.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (scan.hasNext()){
            list.add(s.next());
        }
        scan.close();
        updateVersionNum = list.get(list.size()-1);
        download.setText(updateVersionNum);
        Log.i("VERSIONNUM", updateVersionNum);

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you read the file again after changing a value? It only refreshes when you load the txt file from storage again when your activity is started

Comment: Yeah I do read it again, the logcat shows:
I/VERSIONNUM 1.12
I/VERSIONNUM 1.12
I/VERSIONNUM 1.13